# Why are the hyperbolic functions defined only for the right-hand side of the graph $x^2 - y^2 = 1?$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

[Definition of hyperbolic functions using $x^2 - y^2 = 1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IPE5.png)

Why is it that when defining the hyperbolic functions we only focus on the right-hand side of this graph? Why is it not possible to do it on the left-hand side? Could the parametrization $\cosh(t), \sinh(t)$ not cover both sides of this graph?

Comment: A continuous parametrization with domain $\mathbf R$ has connected image, so you can't get both branches of the hyperbola with a single continuous parametrization.

Comment: @KCd, so it would technically be possible to do the parametrization on the left-hand side as well, instead of the right-hand side?

Comment: The right-hand side of the hyperbola alone provides values for $\cosh t$ and $\sinh t$ (and the rest) for all $t$ from negative infinity to positive infinity. (The area bounded by an arm of the hyperbola and its asymptotes is infinite.) Therefore, the domain associated with the left-hand side would need to reside outside the real numbers.

Comment: From a parametrization $(f(t),g(t))$ of the right branch we easily get a parametrization of the left branch using $(-f(t),g(t))$, so there is nothing technically new involved.

Comment: @KCd, would it not be possible to parametrize the left-branch using f(t),g(t)?